# Increase the width of RelativeLayout

Tags: android, android-relativelayout, expandable

I have two layouts - 1 RelativeLayout and 1 CustomScrollView. The scroll view is placed below the relative layout.

I want to increase/decrease the size of the relative layout when a user taps on it and also move the scroll view accordingly.

Basically I want to have an expandable relative layout and the scroll view to remain below the relative layout at all times.

In onClick method I've tried something like this:

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) userDescriptionContainer.getLayoutParams();
params.height = 7000;
userDescriptionContainer.setLayoutParams(params);
```

but it doesn't seem to have any efect.

Can anyone please tell me how can I accomplish this effect.
Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Try this one:

```
 RelativeLayout graphView=(RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.RR_dashview_graphView);
     LayoutParams params = graphView.getLayoutParams();
     //Changes the height and width to the specified *pixels*
       params.width  = 100; // add your width here.
           params.height = 100; // add your height here.
```

I hope it will help you

Thanks

Comment: And what is the difference between my code and yours despite the fact that you findViewById?

Answer (score -1):

```
RelativeLayout Rl = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relativelayout);

RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layout_description = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams (YourUserDefinedwidth, YourUserDefinedHeight);

Rl.setLayoutParams(layout_description);
```